# Visual studio project template get visual studio version

Tags: visual-studio, extensibility

I'm writing a project template for Visual Studio.

In some of the files generated, I have a string which depends on visual studio version.

Can I get the visual studio version from the template file? I'd like to write

```
<MyCustomString>MyVariable.$visualstudioversion$</MyCustomString>
```

in the template which would expand to

```
<MyCustomString>MyVariable.14.0</MyCustomString>
```

in visual 2015 and

```
<MyCustomString>MyVariable.15.0</MyCustomString>
```

in visual 2017?

Any workaround would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem doesn't exist, since I can detect it directly from the vcxproj file, using

```
$(VisualStudioVersion)
```

which expands to 14.0 in visual 2015 and 15.0 in visual 2017.